# Why does this code give same question twice?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am creating a quiz with **winform** and the function is that this code generates rand number and then give the following question. But when i start it sometimes it don't generate a question so i have press twice or sometimes it generates same question twice. How can i improve this code and make so that it generate a number and if the number is as the if statement it give the question otherwise it generate again a number and do the same thing?

```
    Random number = new Random();
    int questionnumber = number.Next(1, 5);

    List<int> generatednumber = new List<int>();
    generatednumber.Add(questionnumber);


    if (questionnumber == 1 & generatednumber.Count != 1)
    {
        groupBox1.Visible = true;
        label2.Text = "Eine Variable besteht aus...?";
        radioButton1.Text = "Name";
        radioButton2.Text = "Datentyp";
        radioButton3.Text = "Wert";
        radioButton4.Text = "Alle oberen 3";
        radioButton5.Text = "Nur aus Name und Datentyp";

    }
    else
    {
        if (questionnumber == 2 & generatednumber.Count != 2)
        {
            groupBox1.Visible = true;
            label2.Text = "Es gibt ... schleifen";
            radioButton1.Text = "2";
            radioButton2.Text = "3";
            radioButton3.Text = "4";
            radioButton4.Text = "Nur 1";
            radioButton5.Text = "Es gibt kein schleifen";


        }
        else
        {
            if (questionnumber == 3 & generatednumber.Count != 3)
            {
                groupBox1.Visible = true;
                label2.Text = "Was beschriebt ein  character 'char' Datentyp?";
                radioButton1.Text = "Nummer";
                radioButton2.Text = "Sätze";
                radioButton3.Text = "Nummer mit kommazahlen";
                radioButton4.Text = "Buchstaben";
                radioButton5.Text = "Es gibt kein 'char' Datentyp";

            }
            else
            {
                if (questionnumber == 4 & generatednumber.Count != 4)
                {
                    groupBox1.Visible = true;
                    label2.Text = "5%4 ergibt...?";
                    radioButton1.Text = "0";
                    radioButton2.Text = "2";
                    radioButton3.Text = "1";
                    radioButton4.Text = "-3";
                    radioButton5.Text = "Nicht definiert";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (questionnumber == 5 & generatednumber.Count != 5)
                    {
                        groupBox1.Visible = true;
                        label2.Text = "string Name='Test by Bishow'; \n Console.WriteLine(Name.Length); ergibt..?";
                        radioButton1.Text = "3";
                        radioButton2.Text = "Test by Bishow";
                        radioButton3.Text = "13";
                        radioButton4.Text = "1";
                        radioButton5.Text = "4";

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
```

Comment: Declare `number` outside of the method

Comment: @viveknuna you mean `Random number = new Random();
        int questionnumber = number.Next(1, 5);`  to declare outside?

Comment: @viveknuna still have the same problem it generate now at first when i click but only same question twice

Comment: No only `Random number = new Random();`

Comment: Also you should use `&&` instead of `&`

Comment: I think you have to declare List<int> generatednumber = new List<int>(); outside the method and check generatednumber.Contains(questionnumber) instead of the count of the list

Comment: Perhaps you can just have a list of question and shuffle it. then send them one by one. that way the same question won't be pick twice as you enumerate the shuffle list of question.

Comment: You can also store your text in class in order to make all this readable. this way you don't have this weird if else if else but just and array of nice object. you want a question you use the index and voila.

Comment: Why the second check in `(questionnumber == N & generatednumber.Count != N)`? Don't you want question 1 as first question, and question 2 as second question, and so on? Are you building an Enigma machine? Apart from showing your code and explaining what it doesn't do, also explain what you think it should do.

Comment: Have you [asked a rubber duck](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)? When you step through the program in the debugger when do things first go awry?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you have to change your code to something like this. I've created a new Method to call which then shows your question. Make sure you declare Random number and List generatedNubmers outside the Method in the class structure.

```
Random number = new Random();
List<int> generatedNumbers = new List<int>();

private void GetNewRandomQuestion(){
   if (generatedNumbers.Count >= 5){ // Since you only have five questions, there can only be five unique numbers. The code below would get stuck
       throw new Exception(); 
   }
   int questionNumber = number.Next(1, 5);
   while (generatedNumbers.Contains(questionNumber)){   // Generate new number until there is a unique one
      questionNumber = number.Next(1, 5);
   } 
   generatedNumbers.Add(questionNumber);
   // The code above made sure the question wasnt there already. You only have to check the questionnumber now

   if (questionNumber == 1){
       //...
   }
   else if {
      //...
  } //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. Just wanted to ask you something if i understood it right:
`while (generatedNumbers.Contains(questionNumber))`does this check if the generated number is conatained on list? I didnt got what actually does this code do  `if (generatedNumbers.Count >= 5){ 
       throw new Exception(); 
   }`

Comment: @Henry You have only five Questions and each Question should only be displayed once. So if every question was already shown (generatedNubmers count would be five) there is no more question to show, so the Method should not display any other Question. Instead of throwing an error you could show a Message box that shows the user he answered every question

Comment: @DragandDrop Of course, this is inefficient especially for the last questions. But since he has only five questions, this code takes only some Milliseconds to execute. For five questions this is enough, also this code remains easy and simple for a beginner like him.

Comment: Random don't work like that. Random has no issue not providing the last number for a time longer that you would expect. Even on a short range like this. Many studies asked student to write random number when they have some time. And human are really bad at random. There are some seed that will not generate the right number for more than 20 try in a row. You only have 1/5 every roll. That's 1- ((4/5)^20) ~98%. But that doesn't address the logic issue.

Comment: I Wrote a little benchmark: For 100 Million iterations (each iteration a new random with new Seed is created), it takes the algorithm about 2,1 Ticks (210ns) to find the 5 in the range 1-5, with a max peek of 23600 ticks (2,36ms). Even for bigger numbers (100 in the range 1-100) it takes in average only 7,9 ticks (790ns) with a peek of 44056 ticks (4,4ms). I see your problem but it makes no sense for such small numbers. Heres the benchmark: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yBllpo